# Discord.js RPC on GTA or Minecraft server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, altv

I would like to make a Rich Presence. Is it possible that I host it on a Minecraft server or an Alt:v GTA server and all Player that join the Server have it in the Status?

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Comment: I know how to code it but i would like to know.Is it possible to host ist on a GTA server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both games it is possible
In the case of GTA V, it is possible to do it, here I leave the official [FiveM Development forum](https://forum.cfx.re/t/release-esx-discord-rich-presence/1531095)

In the case of Minecraft, it is possible to do it and there are two ways
1- Through Personalized Client [Help Link](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/craftpresence)

> You can join the mod in the root folder of your custom client

2- Through Server with Mods [Help Link](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/discordrichpresence-customizer.59796/updates)

> Just make sure you set it up right

P.S. Sorry for my English, I'm from Mexico